# Error testing file reading function with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a simple function:

```
def read_file(fp):
    with open(fp) as fr:
        for line in fr.readlines():
            yield line
```

When I run this function on a non-existent file, I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'idontexist.txt'
```

In another file, I am trying to test this function using `pytest`:

```
import pytest
from utils import read_file

def test_file_not_exist():
    filepath = 'idontexist.txt'
    with pytest.raises(FileNotFoundError):
        read_file(filepath)
```

However, running `pytest`, I get the message:

```
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'FileNotFoundError'>
```

Why does this test not pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a generator function. Calling the generator function returns a generator object:

```
>>> def read_file(fp):
...     with open(filepath) as fr:
...         for line in fr.readlines():
...             yield line
... 
>>> read_file('asd')
<generator object read_file at 0x10554ee08>
```

The open call (which should raise FileNotFoundError) will not be called until you loop over the generator. Then you will see

```
>>> g = read_file('asd')
>>> for x in g:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in read_file
NameError: name 'filepath' is not defined
```

I am guessing that you half-changed `fp` to `filepath` before posting here. You can fix that but either way you won't see any error from `read_file` unless you consume the returned generator by iterating over it.

**EDIT**: I don't recommend using a `with` statement inside a generator like this. The reason is that there is no guarantee that the file will be closed.

To understand this consider what the purpose of `with` is. Before context managers you would open a file like

```
f = open(filename)
f.read(4)
# etc
f.close()
```

The problem with this is that the file may not get closed if something happens (e.g. an exception or `return` etc) between the `open` and the `close`. You can fix this with `try/finally` i.e.

```
f = open(filename)
try:
    f.read(4)
    # etc
finally:
    f.close()
```

This is cumbersome so we have the `with` statement to shorten it to

```
with open(filename) as f:
    f.read(4)
    # etc
```

This is good because it reduces clutter and there's no way to leave the `with` statement without the file being closed. However when you do it in a generator like your `read_file` above someone might call the generator with

```
for line in read_file(filename):
    if line.startswith('#'):
        break
```

Now after the `break` the generator is suspended at the `yield` it has no way to know that it will not be iterated on again so it waits there. The `yield` inside the `with` block allows you to leave the context manager without closing the file. (The same problem would also occur when using `try/finally` but it's perhaps more obvious in that case.) Even if you know that you won't `break` an exception from the loop body will have the same effect.

What happens in this case is that the file will *probably* be closed as a result of the ref-counting GC in CPython: when the generator is collected it will be closed, an exception is thrown in terminating the `with` block and hence closing the file. This isn't much better than allowing the GC to collect the file object `f` directly (which also closes the file through `file.__del__`).

The simple rule is:

> Don't `yield` inside a `with` statement

That means you should usually take the `with` statement outside the generator. So you do something like

```
def read_file(f):
    for line in f.readlines():
        yield line

# Control resource at top level
with open(filename) as fin:
    for line in read_file(fin) # pass the resource to generator
        # do something with line
```

**Another point**: the whole point of iterators is that they allow us not to have to do things like read a whole file into memory. So rather than calling `readlines()` which reads the while file into memory you should iterate over the file directly which only reads one line at a time. With these two changes your function looks like:

```
def read_file(f):
    for line in f:
        yield line
```

Or even:

```
def read_file(f):
    yield from f
```

In terms of iterators this is just the identity function so it is redundant and can be removed. So wherever you use the `read_lines` function you can instead just use

```
with open(filename) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # do stuff
```

(i.e. there is no `read_lines` function in the code any more)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! Related question: is the `open` called once for every element in the generator stream?

Comment: No open is only called when the first element is requested. The rules for a generator function mean that it will proceed until the first `yield` when you ask for the first element. Also I don't recommend using `with` inside a generator function like this - I'll update the answer to explain why.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!